# Array_Search For Multiple Same Elements

Tags: php, arrays

there is an array like `$arr = array(1,2,3,3,3,4,5)` . What if we want to get all indexes that have values 3?

i used `array_search(3, $arr)` but it just give back an integer and just the first index that has value '3'

how can we get an array like `$indexes = array(2,3,4)` that shows all indexes that have value 3?

your help will be highly appreciated

Comment: A Foreach loop ?

Comment: you surely have to code some kind of loop here. What have you tried so far ?

Comment: This is actually explained in the [`array_search` manual page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php#function.array-search.returnvalues) - *If needle is found in haystack more than once, the first matching key is returned. To return the keys for all matching values, use array_keys() with the optional search_value parameter instead.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `array_keys` with search value [PHP Doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php)

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/kfTZH)

```
array_keys($arr,3)
```

---

> `array_keys()` returns the keys, numeric and string, from the array.
>
> If a search_value is specified, then only the keys for that value are
>   returned. Otherwise, all the keys from the array are returned.

Answer (score 1):

With that solution you can create complex filters. In this case we compare every value to be the number three (=== operator). The filter returns the index, when the comparision true, else it will be dropped.

```
$a = [1,2,3,4,3,3,5,6];

$threes = array_filter($a, function($v, $k) {
  return $v === 3 ? $k : false; },
  ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH
);
```

`$threes` Is an array containing all keys having the value 3.

> array(3) { 2, 4, 5 }

Answer (score 1):

you can use array_keys:

```
foreach (array_keys($arr) as $key) if ($arr[$key] == 3) $result[] = $key;
```